# Ordinary kriging stationary case

Tags: spatial, interpolation, kriging

I am trying to understand ordinary kriging.

Say I have 3 elevation measurements: Z1, Z2, and Z3 taken at X positions: X1, X2 and X3.

I am also assuming some semivariogram: g(h) and that the process is stationary.

From what I understand the kriging weights in this case should be ?:

$ L = M^{-1}*Gs $

Where:

$L=\ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
l_1 \\
l_2 \\
l_3 \\
\mu\end{array} \right) $

$\
M = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
g(0) && g(X2-X1) && g(X3-X1) && 1 \\
g(X2-X1) && g(0) && g(X3-X2) && 1 \\
g(X3-X1) && g(X3-X2) && g(0) && 1 \\
1 && 1 && 1 && 0 \end{array} \right)$

$Gs=\ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
g(|X1 - Xs|) \\
g(|X2 - Xs|) \\
g(|X3 - Xs|) \\
1
\end{array} \right) $

And the elevation Zs at x position Xs should be estimated by ?:

$\ Z(Xs)=\sum_{i=1}^3 l_i*Zi$

Will the inverse of the matrix pose a problem?
I found a Matlab script on the internet that was using "Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse" instead.

The reason I am asking this question is that I coded a Matlab script on this which drew random X and Z; and it seemed to work just fine most times, but every now and then it returned a "crazy" estimate for Z(Xs).

So I am just trying to understand if I have misunderstood the theory, if the inverse of the matrix sometimes become "ill posed" or if I have just tripped up in my Matlab coding.

Here is my Matlab script:

```
% kriging.m
n = 3;
X = 1000*rand(1,n);
Z = 1000 + 100*randn(1,n);
stem(X,Z,'b');
hold on;

a0 = 300; % range
c0 =   4; % scale

M = ones(n+1,n+1);
for r = 1 : n
    for c = 1 : n
        Xr = X(r);
        Xc = X(c);
        h = abs(Xr - Xc);
        M(r,c) = c0*(1-exp( -(h/a0)^2 ));
    end
end
M(n+1,n+1) = 0

MI = inv(M)

Xs = 500;
hs = abs(X - Xs);
Gs = c0*(1-exp( -(hs/a0).^2 ));
Gs = [Gs 1]'

L = MI*Gs;
L = L(1:n)

Zs = Z*L

stem(Xs,Zs,'r')
```

And here is an example of an crazy result:

```
X =

  117.4177  296.6759  318.7783


Z =

  1.0e+003 *

    0.9679    1.0012    0.6971


M =

         0    1.2010    1.4508    1.0000
    1.2010         0    0.0217    1.0000
    1.4508    0.0217         0    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000         0


MI =

   -0.8331    5.2214   -4.3883    1.0956
    5.2214  -55.8175   50.5960   -6.3666
   -4.3883   50.5960  -46.2077    6.2710
    1.0956   -6.3666    6.2710   -1.4516


Gs =

    3.2134
    1.4732
    1.2229
    1.0000


L =

    0.7441
   -9.9423
   10.1982


Zs =

 -2.1255e+003
```

[image]

Comment: If you are using a valid semivariogram, you should never run into these difficulties. However, for certain data configurations and certain variograms you can get *close* to singular matrices. (I have never seen kriging software that uses a pseudoinverse--that would be appropriate only when data fall on a regular grid or when all data are used at once; directly solving the system $ML=G_s$ is more stable and far more efficient in most applications.) What semivariogram are you using that causes problems? BTW, did you really mean to put absolute values in the expression for $G_s$ but not in $M$?

Comment: Hi whuber. Thanks for the help! I am using a Gaussian semivariogram.

Comment: Gaussians can produce such strange results, Andy: because they and their derivatives are zero at the origin, they impose extreme smoothness on the kriged estimates. In the bottom picture, fitting a smooth spline (as a proxy for the kriging) clearly would extrapolate high values in the 150-250 range. Such extrapolation requires weights beyond the 0-1 range. The extremely low value you have plotted at 500 similarly looks consistent with the data and variogram.  Why not experiment first with an exponential variogram (and add a tiny nugget to it)?

Comment: Thanks. I understand now that the result value is not so crazy after all. Besides I want to do interpolation, not extrapolation so this case is not so important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo inverses are used when the matrix is not of full rank and hence a true inverse does not exist meaning also that there is not a unique solution.  Taking a Moore-Penrose psuedoinverse is a way of picking a particular solution.  You can Google Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse and I bet you will find out alot about it. If you use it as a key phrase using this sites search engine you will probably find places where it has appeared in previous questions.

Comment: The kriging equations are set up to guarantee that the matrix $M$ is always of full rank, Michael.  It is an error to use a semivariogram $g$ that would produce a singular $M$. This issue is likely tangential to understanding OK and the Matlab script.

Comment: My comment was made because the OP mentioned a Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.  The Moore-Penrose inverse is a generalized inverse.  You wouldn't be using it if M was nonsingular!

Comment: Here:  Look at this which was obtained by googling Moore-Penrose Inverse and finding this Wikipedia source. In mathematics, and in particular linear algebra, a pseudoinverse A+ of a matrix A is a generalization of the inverse matrix.[1] The most widely known type of matrix pseudoinverse is the Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse, which was independently described by E. H. Moore[2] in 1920, Arne Bjerhammar [3] in 1951 and Roger Penrose[4] in 1955.

Comment: Contiuation of quote from Wikipedia:  Earlier, Fredholm had introduced the concept of a pseudoinverse of integral operators in 1903. When referring to a matrix, the term pseudoinverse, without further specification, is often used to indicate the Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse. The term generalized inverse is sometimes used as a synonym for pseudoinverse.
A common use of the Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse (hereafter, just pseudoinverse) is to compute a 'best fit' (least squares) solution to a system of linear equations that lacks a unique solution (see below under Applications).

Comment: Final continuation of Wikipedia quote: Another use is to find the minimum (Euclidean) norm solution to a system of linear equations with multiple solutions. The pseudoinverse facilitates the statement and proof of results in linear algebra.

Comment: @whuber Sorry Bill I misread your post. But the mention of the Moore-Penrose inverse in the Matlab post is an indication of an error there. But what makes kriging so special that you could guarantee a unique solution based on three points?  Couldn't the data cause a singularity with spatial fitting just like the design matrix can do in ordinary least squares regression?

Comment: Michael, notice that the elevations themselves are not involved in the matrix equations. The matrix elements depend entirely on the geometric configuration of the sample locations. It is a *requirement* of kriging that the "semivariogram" $g$ be such that *for all possible configurations* of distinct points, $M$ be positive-definite and therefore nonsingular. The presence of a pseudoinverse in the algorithm therefore smacks of papering over a deeper problem, such as using an invalid or unstable variogram.

Comment: I am not an expert on this.  You probably know a lot more than me and maybe have read Michael Stein's book where I have it collecting dust on my book shelf. The point that we both can agree on is that figuring this out requires more details from the Matlab writeup and/or more experimentation with the data